bash: /usr/local/bin/shopt: No such file or directory
I mainly run zsh as non-root user but I run bash as root ($echo $SHELL gives me /bin/bash). In my .bashrc file from root there the following line
shopt -s histappend

when I execute source /root/.bashrc, I get the following error:
bash: /usr/local/bin/shopt: No such file or directory

I also looked for shopt in /usr with the command sudo find . -iname "shopt" which did not give me any result
I already had a look at the following question which didn't help me to solve the problem:
shopt command not found in .bashrc after shell updation

shopt is supposed to be a bash builtin, so not finding it in the filesystem is expected and having it resolve to /usr/local/bin/shopt is very weird. What does command -v shopt show?

thanks a lot @Ry: that was right to the point: it showed alias shopt=/usr/local/bin/shopt which I had created (don't know when: maybe when I was under macos). I remove the alias and it worked. Many thanks
